# error: WebGL warning: texImage2D: Desired upload requires more data than is available: (when loading the texture with triangle mesh data and normals)

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, textures, webgl2

i probably have messed up when i load 2 textures. i am getting this error :"WebGL warning: texImage2D: Desired upload requires more data than is available: (0 rows plus 246 pixels needed, 0 rows plus 244 pixels available)"

and nothing in the screen. I have 2 textures one with the vertices of a mesh and another with the normals. i will post the way i try to load the textures:

```
const uLSr = gl.getUniformLocation(P, 'uMeshData');
const uNormData = gl.getUniformLocation(P, 'uNormData');

const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

 const verts = [
         ...
         4.910892,0.000000,4.910892,
        -4.910892,0.000000,-4.910892,
        -4.910892,0.000000,4.910892,
        4.910892,0.000000,4.910892,
        4.910892,0.000000,-4.910892,
        ...
];

const vertsNorm = [
        ...
        0.0000,-1.0000,0.0000,
        0.4253,-0.8506,0.3090,
        -0.1625,-0.8506,0.5000,
        0.7236,-0.4472,0.5257,
        0.4253,-0.8506,0.3090,
        ...
];

const meshVerts = new Float32Array(verts);
    const vertsLenght = meshVerts.length / 3;
    gl.uniform1i(uLvertices, vertsLenght);

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB32F, vertsLenght, 1, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, meshVerts);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


const textureNorm = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureNorm);

const meshNorm = new Float32Array(vertsNorm);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
//vertsLength is the same cause normal and vertices have the same length
//foreachone normal there is one single vertex
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB32F, vertsLenght, 1, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, meshNorm);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

and then in the draw function i call them like that:

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureNorm);
gl.uniform1i(uLSr, 0);
gl.uniform1i(uNormData, 1);
```

and then inside the shader  i try to unpack them like that:

```
for (int i = 6; i < vertsCount; i += 3) {

    a = texelFetch(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
    b = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
    c = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

    aN = texelFetch(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
    bN = texelFetchOffset(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
    cN = texelFetchOffset(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

    triangleNormal = (aN.xyz + bN.xyz + cN.xyz) / 3.;

    vec3 uvt;
    vec3 intersect;
    float z;
    bool isHit = hitTriangleSecond(R_.orig, R_.dir, a.xyz, b.xyz, c.xyz, uvt, triangleNormal, intersect, z);;
    if (isHit) {

        if (z<mindist && z > 0.001) {
            hitPos1 = intersect;

            mindist = z;
            weHitSomething = true;
            material.type = DIEL;
            material.albedo = vec3(.8, .3, .4);
            normal = triangleNormal;
            hitPos = hitPos1;            
        }
    }      
}
```

if i comment the line where i calculate the normal of the surface and then replace it with the normal i got from texture i got a white page. So i assume i have made something wrong with the loading of the textures. Or is it in the HitTriandglSecond function where i calculate the face normal of the triangle?

and below i post the link to the jsfiddle with a minimal example(its long cause i put the vertices and normals of a plane and a sphere of triangles):
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/dominuss/fsgd6La3/2/) of jsfiddle example

Comment: I also wan to say that i have exported the files from blender in .obj format and i wrote a object parser to convert them to the format i want. I can post this code too if you want as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB32F, vertsLenght, 1, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, meshNorm);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

i found the mistake.

it was the vertsLength variable, i made a new variable for the second texture cause to reuse the vertsLength didnt seem to work some reason.

```
const normLength = meshNorm.length /3;
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB32F, normLength, 1, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, meshNorm);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```